# Find limit using Maclaurin power series

Tags: limits, power-series, taylor-expansion

I encountered the following problem:

$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x-\ln(1+x)}{x-\arctan x} $$

I expanded $ \arctan x $ in the denominator up to the fifth term and get the following:

$$ x - \left(x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + O(x^5)\right) = \frac{x^3}{3!} + O(x^5)$$

And I expanded $\ln(1+x) $ in the numerator up to the fourth term and get:

$$ x - \left(x - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + O(x^4)\right) = \frac{x^2}{2!} - \frac{x^3}{3!} + O(x^4) $$

So here is the step where I got stuck:

$$  \frac{\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^3}{6} + O(x^4)}{\frac{x^3}{6} + O(x^5)} $$

If I factor out $x^3$, I'm left with:

$$ \frac{\frac{1}{2x} - \frac{1}{6} + O(x)}{\frac{1}{6} + O(x^2)} $$

So I'm still not able to substitute $ x=0$ since there is a term with $1 \over 2x$. So how do I deal with this problem? Did I miss something during the progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not miss anything (although you may want to check the expansion for the denominator, I think there is a mistake there in the constant$^{(\dagger)}$). Actually, expanding the numerator to order $x^2$ (first non-zero order) is enough.

Your fraction will behave like $$\frac{\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)}{\frac{x^3}{3}+o(x^3)}\operatorname*{\sim}_{x\to 0}\frac{3}{2x}$$ on a neighborhood of zero, meaning that the limit does not exist (it will tend to $\pm\infty$ depending on whether $x\to 0^+$ or $0^-$).

$(\dagger)$ $\arctan x  = x-\frac{x^3}{3} + o(x^4)$, there is no factorial. The same applies for $\ln(1+x)$, actually: $\ln(1+x) = x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+o(x^3)$, there are no factorials in the coefficients.

Comment: Thank you! Good reminder of the $\arctan x$ and $ln(1+x)$ expansion too! Appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome! (Also, small tip: when in doubt, don't hesitate to doublecheck your asymptotics with [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+(x-ln(1%2Bx))%2F(x-arctan+x)+at+x%3D0+to+order+3).)